# How to unzip a zip file in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, zip, aws-cli

I want to write some validation code on the files present in a zip folder in s3. I am having trouble in unzipping it. I have tried to download it and then unzip it and then upload it but this process takes a lot of time. Is there any way by which this can be done without downloading and uploading.

Comment: Which programming language are you planning to use? There should be a library that will handle zip files already

Comment: I am trying to do it using pyspark @AmanB

Comment: What is the range of file sizes? Similarly file counts?

Answer (score 1):

A couple things to consider with speed of s3.

Issue 1. How big are you zip files?
 Issue 2. Where are running you validation code?  If you are running it outside of AWS then you could be experiencing network related issues.

Not much to do with issue 1, large files are large files. However, with issue 2 the closer you run your validation code to S3 the better.  For this you have two options.

Option 1: Use an EC2 instance. If you are dealing with really large zip files than some instance types provide better network performance than others.  But I would start with t3 and see how that works for you.

Option 2: Use a lambda. The benefit with using a Lambda is you can create an S3 Event Trigger that calls you lambda when every zip file is uploaded.

Also, an optimization you could do if you are just uploading the zip after validation without changing the content is to use the s3 mv command.